# Freeing resources associated with items

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactivex

I am implementing some multi-stage pipeline-style processing with RxJava3. I use several consecutive `.concatMap` calls for the individual steps. As a side effect, the steps create some (large) temporary files that should be deleted on both error and success. The first step hands over the files to the next one. I successfully use `Single.using` to close the file handles, but can't delete the file this way, as it would be gone before the next step can use it. Deleting the file in `doOnError` of the first step, and in `using` in the second step works in most cases.

However, there is a corner case where the file "leaks", i.e. is not deleted: If the second step of the first work item fails (throws an exception) *after* the second item has completed its first (first `concatMap`) step but not yet begun its *second* step (second `concatMap`), that second item is in some intermediate place and not deleted, as it is not currently captured in any `using` scope.

My minimal example is:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import java.io.File
import io.reactivex.Single
import java.io.FileOutputStream

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Observable.just(5, 4).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .concatMapSingle { workItem ->
            val file = File("/tmp/foo/work$workItem")
            Single.using({ FileOutputStream(file) }, { oStream ->
                Single.just(oStream)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .map { os ->
                        println("Pretending to work on item $workItem")
                        os.write("File $workItem".toByteArray())

//                      if (Math.random () > 0.5) throw Exception ("Something else failed")

                        Thread.sleep(workItem.toLong() * 1000)  // Second work item should have a quicker first step than the second step of the first item
                        Pair(file, workItem)    // Propagate both file and item number
                    }.doOnError { println("Deleting ${file.absolutePath}"); file.delete() }
            }, { os -> println("Closing file ${file.absolutePath}"); os.close(); })
        }
        .concatMapSingle { data1 ->
            Single.using({ data1 }, { data2 ->
                Single.just(data2)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                    .map { data ->
                        val workItem = data.second
                        println("Continuing pretend work on item ${workItem}");

                        Thread.sleep(workItem.toLong() * 1000)

                        // ... More complex stuff here ...

                        if (workItem == 5) throw Exception("Something failed")
                    }
            }, { data -> println("Deleting ${data.first.absolutePath}"); data.first.delete(); })
        }.blockingSubscribe();
}
```

If the exception is thrown, the file `/tmp/foo/work4` is not deleted, as the work item "4" waits for 1s to be processed by the 2nd `concatMap`. The output is:

```
Pretending to work on item 5
Closing file /tmp/foo/work5
Continuing pretend work on item 5
Pretending to work on item 4
Closing file /tmp/foo/work4
Deleting /tmp/foo/work5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Something failed
    at io.reactivex.internal.util.ExceptionHelper.wrapOrThrow(ExceptionHelper.java:46)
    [...]
```

If the first (commented out) or no exception throws, everything is deleted fine. The problem is the same with `flatMap`, but harder to debug, as more things are running in parallel.

Therefore, my question is: Can I associate some "clean-up" function with the items (here: 5, 4) that is always called when that item goes out of scope?

Comment: The item lifecycle is not part of the RxJava model. The best you can do is `using` but then there might not be a good way to scope items. If you are on Java 9+, you could work something out with its [Cleaner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) support.

Comment: Since this has to work on Android 7.1 I can only use Java 7/8...